# Foursquare API: Consider close proximity as check-in

Tags: ios, api, location, foursquare, checkin

I've been looking into the Foursquare API on iOS (through [das-quadrat](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/das-quadrat)). I'd like to figure out if a user *is at* a specific location. I know how to find it and I can actually get it. That works.

How can I now tell if the user is actually close enough to the location to consider his close proximity as a check-in (I'm not interested in actually checking him in the Foursquare way)? It's just that I want to know that a user is at a venue of a category I'm monitoring. I know that I can just calculate the distance between the user's location and the venue's location and consider every distance less than, say, 15 meters a check-in but I was wondering if there's is a more elegant solution, maybe even an API endpoint that I'm just missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the real time API is best suited: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime

Allows you to register for notifications, thus Foursquare does the heavy lifting for you.